# Authentication of WSDL Webservices using P12 certificate in ios

Tags: authentication, wsdl

### Heading ##I am working on WSDL webservices. Client has provided certificate p12 for authentication of these webservice.

I have implemented following code for the single certificate which i have added in my bundle.

```
         (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:
(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge

{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        identity = [self getClientCertificate];
        CFArrayRef certs = [self getCertificate];
        NSArray *myArray = (__bridge NSArray *)certs;
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity
        certificates:myArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

(CFArrayRef)getCertificate
{
    SecCertificateRef certificate = nil;
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate);
    SecCertificateRef certs[1] = {certificate};
    CFArrayRef array = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **) certs, 1, NULL);
    SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecTrustRef myTrust;

    OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(array, myPolicy, &myTrust);
    if (status == noErr){
        NSLog(@"No Err creating certificate");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Possible Err Creating certificate");
    }
    return array;
}

(SecIdentityRef)getClientCertificate
{
    SecIdentityRef identityApp = nil;
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"p12"];
    NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;
    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("Password1");
    const void *keys[] = {kSecImportExportPassphrase}; //kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = {password};
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);
    CFRelease(options);
    CFRelease(password);
    if (securityError == errSecSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
        CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                kSecImportItemIdentity);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
    }
    return identityApp;
}
```

It Works fine for single certificate. But now the client has new requirement that the certificate won't be single. It will be different for every user. Users will be emailed certificate p12, from where user can download.

**Issue**: iPhone's provisioning profile where the certificate will be installed is in different sandbox and the App is in another.

How can such certificates be accessed without knowing the credentials (username and password) without keeping it in bundle.

Thanks in advance.